# Reading json data return to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using the following code to get some json formatted data:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "MyService.svc/GetSomeData",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data, textStatus) {

                alert("Test: " + data.toString());
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + (errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));
            }
        });
```

Data is successfully returned to this call, and it looks like this:

```
{"d":"test data"}
```

My guess was that I could access the data as follows:

```
var myData = data["d"];
```

However this seems to always return "undefined".  What am I missing to get the single string of data "test data"?

Comment: You only have access to data['d'] in the callback. Is that where you are trying to get the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what happens if you try `data.d`?

Answer (score 8):

Change `dataType: "text",` to `dataType: "json",`

The problem you're having is that while the returned string is in fact valid JSON, it is being returned to your success function as a string.  Strings don't have an attribute called `d`.  What you need to do is convert the JSON to a javascript object -- which jQuery will do for you if you tell it that you're expecting JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think both Sean & Thiago are correct:  use `{dataType: "json"}` (in your options to $.ajax()) and access the value with `data.d`.

Comment: data["d"] will work just as fine as data.d.  JavaScript object properties can be (and sometimes must be) referenced through array notation.