# How to separate the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i am using this code to get the values from the java class.

here i am getting the values from java, and alerting the value using the data.
The data is returning two values separated by spaces.

now i want to separate the values. after separating the values, i will get two values and that two values i want to assign it for two variables..

How can i do this?

code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#refresh").click(function(){
                   var fileId=id;
                   var rowNum = $(this).parent().parent().index();;
                   $.ajax({
                   type:"post",
                    url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
                   data:{fileId:fileId},
                    success:function(data)
                   {

                    alert(data);
               }
</script>
```

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278999/jquery-string-split-the-string-after-the-space-using-split-method

Comment: I don't know if this is your complete code, but there seem to be some brackets missing. I am surprised you are getting the `alert` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be chance that your actual data is inside the "data" variable.
so you can actually use

data.variable for actual content and then use split function of javascript.
Ex .

```
var actualData = data.variable.split(' ');
var x = actualData[0];
var y = actualData[1];
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try with javascript split function for example 
data.split

```
var elem = data.split(' ');//separate the values when find a white space
var a = elem[0]
var b = elem[1]
```

Comment: You used `''` instaed of `' '`, `''` could have apart every characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var elem1 = data.split(" ")[0];
var elem2 = data.split(" ")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 success:function(data)
        {
          var data=data.d;
          var datas=data.split(' ');
          var data1=datas[0];
          var data2=datas[1];
          alert(data1 + '-----'+ data2); //For Test
         }
```

Comment: What is `var data=data.d;` ? if I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem correct, is this a typo, can you fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613728/reading-a-string-table-jquery-ajax-success-function  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427855/reading-json-data-return-to-jquerysee  what is data.d

Comment: Can you explain it, can you make this work ? that is a `c#` and `json`, I really don't know it.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/tW58v/), please check it.

Comment: data.d that means, d is attribute in data returned by jquery ajax

Comment: where is your jquery in fiddle your question tag with jquery.

Comment: From the question `The data is returning two values separated by spaces`.

Comment: That is ajax success function.

Comment: It's about splitting a text separated by a space and nothing to do with `ajax`.

Comment: it's not any `json` object returned by the `ajax` and even it were then there must be a `d` property.

Comment: Here `data` is a string which contains a sentence (two words) separated by space.

Comment: ok it's not any json object then remove 1st line of my code //var data=data.d;

Comment: You should fix it, otherwise you'll get down votes, just trying to help you, nothing else. hope you got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#refresh").click(function(){
                   var fileId=id;
                   var rowNum = $(this).parent().parent().index();;
                   $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"checkStatusAndNumRecs",
                        data:{fileId:fileId},
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                           alert(data);
                           var vals=data.split(' ');
                           var a=vals[0];
                           var b=vals[1];
                           //do something with these values
                        }
                   });
                 });
```